# Publish in on_message with Paho Mqtt Client not working

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

The publish call in the main method dosen't send a message to the broker, but returns (0,2). on_publish won't be called.
I am not sure how I should look where the error is. I tried qos=2 and run the main method async but it didn't fixed it. The base connection work, because the on_message is called. The mqtt-server works fine with other projects too.
Has anyone some ideas?

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import subprocess
import shutil
import os
import glob
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

direction = 19
pwm = 26
GPIO.setup(direction, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(pwm, GPIO.OUT)

pwm = GPIO.PWM(pwm,19000)
speed = 0
pwm.start(speed)
running = False

client = mqtt.Client()
#First: pip3 install paho-mqtt
print("Starte Listener")

def start():
    GPIO.output(direction, GPIO.LOW)
    for dc in range(10, 40, 1):
        speed = dc 
        pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(speed)
        time.sleep(0.25)

def end():
    GPIO.output(direction, GPIO.LOW)
    for dc in list(reversed(range(0,40,1))):
        speed = dc 
        pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(speed)
        time.sleep(0.5)


def main(mqttClient):
    print("Started Spinning")
    running = True
    start()
    print(mqttClient.publish("scanner","shoot"))
    print("Waiting 124 seconds")
    time.sleep(124)
    print("ending spinning")
    end()
    print("finished spinning")
    running = False 

def on_connect2(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.subscribe("scanner",2)
    print("Connected "+str(rc))
    

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(mqttClient, userdata, msg):
    print("Recived message: "+str(msg.payload,'UTF-8'))
    if(str(msg.payload,'UTF-8') == "spin" and running == False):
        main(mqttClient)

def disconnected():
    print("Disconneted")

def on_publish(self, client, userdata, mid):
    print("onPublish")
    print(client,userdata,mid)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
client.enable_logger(logger)

client.on_connect = on_connect2
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.on_disconnect = disconnected
client.username_pw_set("....","....")
client.connect("gx1", 1883,60)
client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: if publish returns (0,2), that implies 0 - publish successful and 2 -message number allocated. Don't know why on_publish doesn't run.From here http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/publishing-messages-mqtt-client/ . Also it looks like' running = True' in 'main' needs 'global running' to change the global var, though that won't affect on_publish running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are blocking the MQTT client thread.

When you call `client.loop_forever()` it takes over the processes main thread and uses it to handle all the MQTT communication. When a new message is received it is picked up from the network stack by the MQTT client thread and turned into the message object that is then passed to the `on_message()` callback. This function runs on the client thread.

When you call `client.publish()` this will do one of 2 things

1. If the message is QOS 0 and smaller than the network MTU it will publish the message.
2. If the message is QOS 1 or 2 or larger than the network MTU then it will queue the  message to be handled by the client thread.

The problem* in your code is that you are blocking the return from `main()` by 124 seconds which in turn is blocking the return of the `on_message()` function so the client thread can not get to publishing your message.

If you want to do things the take a long time or block in the `on_message()` (or any of the callback functions) you should start a separate thread to run them on.

*In theory your message looks like it should fall into case 1 listed above, but there may be other factors that are causing it to queue)

Answer (score 0):

As a quickfix I created a new Client:

```
def main(mqttClient):
    print("Started Spinning")
    running = True
    start()
    mq = mqtt.Client("shot_idicator")
    mq.username_pw_set("...","...")
    mq.connect("gx1", 1883,60)
    mq.publish("scanner","shoot")
    mq.disconnect()
    mq = None
    print("Waiting 124 seconds")
    time.sleep(124)
    print("ending spinning")
    end()
    print("finished spinning")
    running = False
```

Now it works but I think this is not how it should be done.